# Symfony How to pass in url the first value of a ManytoMany relation?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my twig, I wanted to pass the name of my category in an url to see the details of this category.

In my controller, I put this as a route :

```php
     **
     * @Route("/{name}", name="category_name", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function categorie(CategoryRepository $categoryRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('category/index.html.twig', [
            'categories' => $categoryRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
```

After, I put this in my twig for get the first value of the name:

```
{% for test in tests %}
    {% set array = test.categories|join(' - ')|split(' ', 2) %}
        <div class="category"><a href="{{ path('category_name', {'name': attribute(array, 0)}) }}">{{ attribute(array, 0) }}</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

My Test class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TestRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TestRepository::class)
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="test_category")
     */
    private $categories;
}
```

My Category class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Test::class, mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $test_category;
}
```

But I have this as an error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "name" for route "category_name" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

Comment: Just the first result? Does just `categories.0.name` work? Of course you could pass that first result only from your controller. But I have to say, I have no idea what `tests` is or where it comes from.

Comment: `categories.0.name` doen't work. I added my Test and Category class in my main post.

Comment: `test.categories|join(' - ')|split(' ', 2)[0]` should work ...

Comment: Always the same error message ...

Comment: might it be that you have no categories at all? or that categories have no name, or that name starts with a space?

Comment: It's works.. the `{{ attribute(array, 0) }}` works between the tags a, but not in the href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess the way you're retrieving the first category's name isn't particularly safe. Try this instead:

```
{% for test in tests %}
    {% set category_name = (test.categories | first).name | default %}
    {% if category_name %}
        <div class="category">
            <a href="{{ path('category_name', {'name': category_name}) }}">
                {{ category_name }}
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

With the use of the `default` filter and the extra `if` we can avoid twig trying to output links when there's no category available.

On a side note, you will run into problems with category name not being URL safe unless you build in checks and safeguards.

The easiest way would be to use the sluggable doctrine extension so that you end up with a URL safe expression of the category name.

See here for details:

- https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/doctrine/common_extensions.html
- https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/sluggable.md